# Using SQL to Copy specific content based on conditions of other colums

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to use either SQL or Excel to copy the picture columns data of the other corresponding picture values for the SAME model and color when the field is NULL.

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/10zwx7m.jpg]

For this picture shown I need D-2 and D-4 to also say A-2.jpg instead of NULL
(It's the same A model and the color is red so copy the existing A model and red picture that's there).  I need D-7 to either copy D-5 or D-6's picture value (A-4.jpg or A-5.jpg would work).  So on....  If there are not particular pictures for that group (ie. model B and Black) then it can be left as NULL.

I'm trying to use group by functions and nested selects, but I am getting nowhere with this.

Comment: Let's see some SQL you've written.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called "products" you might be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE products p SET picture = (
SELECT picture 
FROM products p2
WHERE p2.model = p.model
AND p2.color = p.model
)
WHERE p.picture IS NULL
```

The rules about update commands vary between different Database systems.  Let us know which database you are using if the above query does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server, you can use a self join to update the table.

```
update r set r.picture = l.picture
from Item l
join Item r on l.model = r.model and l.color=r.color
where 
l.picture is not null and 
r.picture is null
```

Comment: Yes, I am on MS SQl Server.  This worked perfectly! Thank you.